# On a function call change State & send value for API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On a function call, i want to change the state value using useState and api call with new value.
But state is not changing immediately.
on callAPI() function call i dont get the new value

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const originalString = "Hello this is my original string";

  const [storeString, setstoreString] = useState(
    "Hello this is my original string"
  );
  const [frontend, setFrontend] = useState(false);
  const [floating, setFloating] = useState(false);

  const callingAPI=(newvalue)=> {
    console.log(newvalue);
  };

  const handleButton = () => {
    if (frontend) {
      setstoreString(storeString.replace("original", "frontend true"));
    }else {
      setstoreString(storeString.replace("original", "frontend true"));

    }
    if (floating) {
      console.log("Current Store", storeString);
      setstoreString(storeString.replace("string", "floating true"));
    }

    callingAPI(storeString);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setFrontend(!frontend)}>Fronend</button>
      <button onClick={() => setFloating(!floating)}>Floating</button>
      <button onClick={handleButton}>Submit</button>
      <div>{storeString}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

on click i get the previous value, but when i click second time i get the new value

Comment: Did you later called this function as myFun()?

Comment: yes, i called it on a button click

Comment: Then it should work. Did you call it like this onClick={()=>myFun()}?

Comment: ```<button onClick={()=>myFun()}>BUTTON</button>```

Comment: no, it doesn't
i got the previous value
but when click second time i get the new value

Comment: i updated the code please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final Output:**

[image]

Call `apiCall()` from `useEffect` instead.

Here is the complete example.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const originalString = "Hello this is my original string";

  const [storeString, setstoreString] = useState([
    originalString,
    originalString
  ]);
  const [frontend, setFrontend] = useState(false);
  const [floating, setFloating] = useState(false);

  const callingAPI = (newvalue) => {
    console.log("Frontend: " + newvalue[0] + "\nFloating: " + newvalue[1]);
    // setstoreString(newvalue);
  };

  const handleButton = () => {
    let temp = [...storeString];
    if (frontend) {
      temp[0] = originalString.replace("original", "frontend true");
      setstoreString(temp);
    } else {
      temp[0] = originalString.replace("original", "frontend false");
      setstoreString(temp);
    }

    if (floating) {
      temp[1] = originalString.replace("original", "floating true");
      setstoreString(temp);
    } else {
      temp[1] = originalString.replace("original", "floating false");
      setstoreString(temp);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    callingAPI(storeString);
  }, [storeString]);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setFrontend(!frontend);
        }}
        style={{ color: frontend ? "green" : "red" }}
      >
        Fronend
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setFloating(!floating);
        }}
        style={{ color: floating ? "green" : "red" }}
      >
        Floating
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleButton}>Submit</button>
      <p style={{ color: frontend ? "green" : "red" }}>{storeString[0]}</p>
      <p style={{ color: floating ? "green" : "red" }}>{storeString[1]}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

You can play with the working project here: [Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-lederberg-sgc9m?file=/src/App.js:0-1020)

Comment: Thank You so much. much appreciated.
but here the problem is: i want both of the state to be true then the api call.
you are missing flating state: 

if (frontend) {
      setstoreString(storeString.replace("original", "frontend true"));
    }else {
      setstoreString(storeString.replace("original", "frontend true"));

    }
    if (floating) {
      console.log("Current Store", storeString);
      setstoreString(storeString.replace("string", "floating true"));
    }

    callingAPI(storeString);

Answer (score 1):

State updates are asynchronous so that's why you don't receive the new value immediately.
A clean way to solve your issue would be to use the `useEffect` hook and do something like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const prevString = useRef();
  const [storeString, setstoreString] = useState(
    "Frontend: [false] ; Floating: [false]"
  );
  const [frontend, setFrontend] = useState(false);
  const [floating, setFloating] = useState(false);

  const callAPI = (newvalue) => {
    console.log(newvalue);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (frontend && floating && prevString.current !== storeString) {
      callAPI(storeString);
    }
    prevString.current = storeString;
  }, [frontend, floating, storeString]);

  const handleButton = () => {
    setstoreString((storeString) => {
      return storeString.replace(/Frontend: \[(false|true)\]/, () => {
        return "Frontend: " + (frontend ? "[true]" : "[false]");
      });
    });
    setstoreString((storeString) => {
      return storeString.replace(/Floating: \[(false|true)\]/, () => {
        return "Floating: " + (floating ? "[true]" : "[false]");
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setFrontend(!frontend)}>Frontend</button>
      <button onClick={() => setFloating(!floating)}>Floating</button>
      <button onClick={handleButton}>Submit</button>
      <div>{storeString}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

When you update the state with `setNewValue`, the component is rerendered.
As `newValue` changes, the `useEffect` hook will be triggered and your API call made as well.

Comment: but i want to call the api when both of the state are true, on useEffect when one state is true then the api will call, that is what i dont want
BTW thank you

Comment: @MHT ok I think I understood your problem. I updated the whole code, I believe it should work like you expect now.